# Python syntactic sugar to generate identical instances of the same class?

Tags: python

Let's say I have this simple class :

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
```

and the following instances :

```py
tom = Person('Tom', 12)
dick = Person('Dick', 14)
harry = Person('Harry', 16)
```

but I want the user of my module to be able to create multiple instances of these people without having to call the `Person` constructor since the `name` and `id` should be declared in only one place.

Options :

1. Use `copy` or `deepcopy`. This will give the functionality I need but every time I want to use a `tom` I will have to remember to create a copy of him. That's clunky.
2. Create a `Tom` class

```py
class Tom(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Tom', 12)
```

This is a bit cleaner since I can just do `Tom()` every time I want to a new `tom`, but this is a lot of code to write and not very DRY.

Is there some other syntactic sugar available in Python that makes this kind of thing easier?

Comment: To be clear: is the goal to create a new instance that is based off an existing instance? (Is the class intended to be mutable? If I mutate the "prototype" and then try to "clone" it, should the change be reflected in new instances?) Or is it to have code that just creates an instance with predetermined parameters? In the latter case, did you consider just... writing a function that calls the constructor a certain way and returns the result? Or maybe you really wanted to be able to *bind arguments to* the constructor call?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel wow I feel dumb -yes, a function that returns the instance is perfect :)

Comment: So the goal is to not repeat the arguments? This seems to be an overly simplified example and may be the Y of an XY problem. Please provide more information.

Comment: You could just create a `clone` method in your `Person` class.  However the phrase "every time I want to use a tom I will have to remember to create a copy of them" suggests that you have a serious flaw in your design.  What's the use case?  Why do you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good use case for a factory / registry type pattern. The idea is to implement an alternative convenience constructor to the class and a single registry dict, which stores the configuration corresponding to a given tag. Take a look at the following example:

```py
PERSON_REGISTRY = {
    "tom": {"name": "Tom", "id": 12},
    "jerry": {"name": "Jerry", "id": 13},
    "dick": {"name": "Dick", "id": 14},
}


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

    @classmethod
    def from_tag(cls, tag):
        """Create a person from a tag"""
        if tag not in PERSON_REGISTRY:
            raise ValueError(f"Not a valid tag {tag}, choose from {list(PERSON_REGISTRY)}")
        
        return cls(**PERSON_REGISTRY[tag])
    
print(Person.from_tag("tom"))
```

Now you can just import the `Person` class and create instances from shorter tags, while the actual data is stored in a single place, the `PERSON_REGISTRY` dict. If you want to reduce verbosity, you could also
use positional arguments, but keyword arguments are usually preferable as being more explicit (Zen of Python).

What is nice about this pattern, is that it is actually extensible. So users could extend the `PERSON_REGISTRY` dict, like:

```py
from persons import Person, PERSON_REGISTRY

PERSON_REGISTRY["liz"] = {"name": "elizabeth", "id": 23}

liz = Person.from_tag("liz")
```

I hope this helps.